# Cannot obtain custom meta information

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta

I'm trying to access custom meta data from a custom post type called 'Videos'

The following code is on a template page called 'single-videos.php'

A custom field called 'Video URL', 'Video Width' and 'Video Height'

However when i run the script, these don't return the values for that particular post.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

```
<?php
/**

*Template Name: Individual Video



*/
get_header('inner');
?>




<section class="section2 portfolio">
      <div class="container">

          <h1 class="title-nml-individual-post text-center gal-title">
    <?php
echo get_the_title($post_id);
?>
   </h1>
        <div class="row" style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px; padding-top: 39px;">

// *** THESE TWO SECTIONS I WAS JUST EXPERIMENTING BUT STILL 
HAD NO LUCK GETTING THE VALUES I NEEDED

<?php
get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
?>

<?php
the_meta($video->ID, 'video_url', true);
?>

<iframe class="wistia_embed" src="" name="wistia_embed" width="<?php
the_meta($video->ID, 'video_width', true);
?>" height="<?php
the_meta($video->ID, 'video_height', true);
?>" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen"></iframe>

        <img class="post-feature-image" src=" <?php
the_post_thumbnail_url('full');
?> "></img>
          </div> <!--end row -->
        </div> <!-- end container-->
    </section>      


<?php
include_once('include/form.php');
?>
<?php
get_footer('inner');
?>
```

[image: Screenshot of WP Admin]

Please let me know if there is anything else i need to provide in the way of details.

Comment: Where did you place the above code?

Comment: Can you please post the whole code, including the loop and how you register the custom meta fields?

Comment: @BorisKuzmanov please see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using a custom template for displaying an individual Video post when there is a single file that is used for this purpose - `single-{post_type}`.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Using the single file, you will be able to get the post ID with `$post->ID` or `get_the_ID()`.

```
if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_url', true );
// you can display all post's information within this loop
endwhile; endif;
```

You can find more about the WordPress Template Hierarchy [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

[image: WordPress Template Hierarchy.]

Comment: Correct, that's why I'm using 'single-videos.php'  as my template file. I made the mistake of using variables $videos instead of $post.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Were you showing all of your Custom Post Type "Video" post on a loop?

Im not sure if your $video->ID matches with your CPT post id.

Try Using get_the_ID() in place of $video->ID 
for reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/